# How to locate tabs on the left side of screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I implemented a simple tab layout by following the [tuturial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

In the tutorial, the tabs are located on top of the screen. Is there any way to locate the tabs on the **left side of the screen** instead of locating tabs on the top? How to change the layout xml file ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

TabActivty doesn't support handle tabs on the left side but here there is a possible alternative:

[Existing patches for android tabwidget to allow tabs on left-hand side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497506/existing-patches-for-android-tabwidget-to-allow-tabs-on-left-hand-side)

Another solution, is to write your own tab widget:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6587ffd8ea4ed74a#